Converting size of removable disk not converting correctly
I am trying to get the total size of a removable disk (such as a USB flash drive), but whenever I try to convert it from bytes to GB, it is not showing the correct size. I have a 64 GB drive showing as 1.89 GB for example (see image--The 64 GB Drive text is the volume label).

I am using the NuGet ByteSize package (but have tried other converters as well with the same results). It does this with any size removable drive. Any ideas as to what might be causing this?
Here is my code:
    private void ReadDrvInfo(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        StrDrvName = d.Name;
        StrDrvType = d.DriveType.ToString();
        if (d.IsReady == true)
        {
            StrDrvLetter = d.RootDirectory.ToString();
            StrVolLabel = d.VolumeLabel;
            StrDrvName = d.Name;
            StrDrvFormat = d.DriveFormat.ToString();
            StrSpaceAvailable = ByteSize.FromBytes((int)d.AvailableFreeSpace).ToString();
            StrTotalFree = ByteSize.FromBytes((int)d.TotalFreeSpace).ToString();
            StrTotalSize = ByteSize.FromBytes((int)d.TotalSize).ToString();
            CBCapacity.Items.Add( StrDrvName + " " +StrVolLabel + " Total size: " + StrTotalSize);
            CBCapacity.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

}

ByteSize.FromBytes what does this do?

This the code the NuGet package ByteSize uses to convert from bytes to a human readable format.

Don't use Str as a prefix.

(int)d.TotalSize <-- Here's (part of) your problem: int (aka Int32) cannot express values larger than 2GB; whereas your TotalSize property is likely typed as Int64 (long).

Given that ByteSize.FromBytes actually accepts a double it's unclear why you are casting in the first place. https://github.com/omar/ByteSize/blob/28f1bd5aa265c4a436e4091cf85fc7ad76bd5083/src/ByteSizeLib/ByteSize.cs#L201

Because your code lacks any local declarations of StrDrvName and StrVolLabel  (and the rest) it means you're mutating instance fields - don't do that: your parent class Form clearly represents (or contains) more than 1 drive/volume/disk, so you shouldn't have single scalar properties that you're re-using in a loop for multiple items.
